# Sending information over sockets to an iPhone MobileSubstrate extension hooked into MobileMail/MobileSafari/MobileMaps

Tags: iphone, sockets, iphone-sdk-3.0, mobile-safari, jailbreak

I am trying to use MobileSubstrate to have a socket listening on a port on various UIKit applications. However, when my extension hooks into MobileSafari, MobileMail or MobileMaps, it is unable to successfully create the socket. I found this page on the iPhone Dev Wiki which clarifies the issue: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Seatbelt .

Is there any way around this for the built in applications to be able to listen on a socket (or open one at all?) If not, what's another good (and easy) way to do interprocess communication on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally for inter-device communication, i use CFMessagePorts which are a lot like mach ports.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMessagePortRef/Reference/reference.html

If all you need is notifications - no data, then i'd suggest looking at the Darwin Notification Center (based off of CFNotificationCenter)